# Stored procedure without string concatenation SQL Injection vulnerabilities

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, sql-injection

I'm using SQL Server 2005/2008, I have a stored procedure that doesn't use string concatenation for generating an EXEC statement, but it does use a dynamic name for the stored procedure.

**I think the @stored_procedure_name and potentially the @object_name parameter are both vulnerable.** However all the Dynamic SQL links I read assume that you are concatenating your SQL statement inside a string - so I'm wondering if it might actually be OK.

Note, just for posting this, I've made the code generic by calling the table objects - so it might not necessarily make logical sense.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_dodgy_sp] 
    @object_name varchar(50) = 'All'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stored_procedure_name varchar(100);

    DECLARE object_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT stored_procedure_name
        FROM [dbo].[objects]
        WHERE [stored_procedure_name] <> ''
        AND ([name] = @object_name)

    OPEN object_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM object_cursor 
        INTO @stored_procedure_name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN

            EXEC @stored_procedure_name @object_id OUTPUT;

            FETCH NEXT FROM object_cursor
                INTO @stored_procedure_name
       END

    CLOSE object_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE object_cursor;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_dodgy_sp] 
    @object_name varchar(50) = 'All'
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stored_procedure_name sysname, @oID INT, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @object_id int;

    DECLARE object_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT object_id, name
        FROM sys.procedures
        WHERE [name] = @object_name

    OPEN object_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM object_cursor 
        INTO @oID, @stored_procedure_name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       BEGIN
            SET @sql = N'EXEC ['+OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@oid)+N'].['+@stored_procedure_name+N'] @Object_id OUTPUT'
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@object_id int OUTPUT', @ObjectId =@object_id OUTPUT

            PRINT @object_id -- we need to do smth with it?

            FETCH NEXT FROM object_cursor
                INTO @oID, @stored_procedure_name
       END

    CLOSE object_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE object_cursor;
END
```

**BUT**

instead of using such a complicated way, may be you just call the parametrized procedure?